# Insert not working using MERGE in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a stored proc with the below query to insert/update using a MERGE in SQL Server but the query works fine for update, but its not working for Insert.
Although I gets correct updated records in Target but for new inserts, it fails.
Basically, i have 4 tables.SUPPORT_STAFF_BAK is the target table which needs to be updated from source table UNIQUE_DUP_TEST based on few conditions from other two tables(REF_FUNCTION,DATA_PERIOD) which i tried to fulfill using joins.
Based on the conditions, we need to check in target, if the same ggid exists for current data_period we need to update it else we need to insert new record again, based on the condition.

```
    MERGE SUPPORT_STAFF_BAK AS SUPP_STAFF
USING 
(SELECT G_UNIQUE.[GLOBAL_ID],

G_UNIQUE.[FIRST_NAME],
G_UNIQUE.[LAST_NAME],
G_UNIQUE.[EMAIL],
G_UNIQUE.[Gender],
G_UNIQUE.[DATE_OF_BIRTH],
G_UNIQUE.[PRODUCTION_UNIT_CODE],
ORG.[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_CODE],
ORG.[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY],
G_UNIQUE.[JOB_NAME],
ORG.[BU_CODE],
ORG.[BU_NAME],
ORG.[SBU_CODE],
ORG.[SBU_NAME],
G_UNIQUE.[GRADE_LETTER],
CASE 
WHEN G_UNIQUE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS] = 'A' THEN 'Active'
WHEN G_UNIQUE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS] = 'S' THEN 'Suspended'
WHEN G_UNIQUE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS]= 'T' THEN 'Terminated' 
END AS [EMPLOYEE_STATUS],
CASE WHEN G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY] = 'DSS' THEN G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL] ELSE '' 
END AS [CATEGORY],
G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL],
G_UNIQUE.[FIRST_JOINING_DATE],
PERIOD.DATA_PERIOD_ID
FROM    UNIQUE_DUP_TEST  G_UNIQUE 
INNER JOIN GDH_ORG ORG
ON G_UNIQUE.PRODUCTION_UNIT_CODE=ORG.PRODUCTION_UNIT_CODE
INNER JOIN REF_FUNCTION FUNC 
ON G_UNIQUE.CATEGORY_DETAIL=FUNC.FUNCTION_CODE 
INNER JOIN DATA_PERIOD PERIOD 
ON FUNC.FUNCTION_ID=PERIOD.FUNCTION_ID 
WHERE  PERIOD.DATA_YEAR=YEAR(GETDATE()) AND PERIOD.DATA_MONTH=MONTH(GETDATE())
) AS G_SOURCE
ON SUPP_STAFF.GGID = G_SOURCE.GLOBAL_ID AND SUPP_STAFF.PRODUCTION_UNIT_CODE=G_SOURCE.PRODUCTION_UNIT_CODE           
    AND SUPP_STAFF.DATA_PERIOD_ID=G_SOURCE.DATA_PERIOD_ID
WHEN MATCHED  THEN 

UPDATE SET 
[SUPP_STAFF].[FIRST_NAME]       = G_SOURCE.[FIRST_NAME],
[SUPP_STAFF].[LAST_NAME]        = G_SOURCE.[LAST_NAME],
[SUPP_STAFF].[EMAIL]            = G_SOURCE.[EMAIL],
[SUPP_STAFF].[GENDER]           = G_SOURCE.[Gender],
[SUPP_STAFF].[DATE_OF_BIRTH]    = G_SOURCE.[DATE_OF_BIRTH],
[SUPP_STAFF].[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_CODE] = G_SOURCE.[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_CODE],
[SUPP_STAFF].[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_NAME] = G_SOURCE.[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY],
[SUPP_STAFF].[GCM_ROLE]         = G_SOURCE.[JOB_NAME],
[SUPP_STAFF].[BU_CODE]          = G_SOURCE.[BU_CODE],
[SUPP_STAFF].[BU_NAME]          = G_SOURCE.[BU_NAME],
[SUPP_STAFF].[SBU_CODE]         = G_SOURCE.[SBU_CODE],
[SUPP_STAFF].[SBU_NAME]         = G_SOURCE.[SBU_NAME],
[SUPP_STAFF].[GRADE]            = G_SOURCE.[GRADE_LETTER],
[SUPP_STAFF].[EMPLOYEE_STATUS]  = G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS],
[SUPP_STAFF].[EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY] = G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY],
[SUPP_STAFF].[START_DATE]       = G_SOURCE.[FIRST_JOINING_DATE],
[SUPP_STAFF].[UPDATE_DATE]      = GETDATE(),
[SUPP_STAFF].[UPDATE_USER]      = CASE  WHEN G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS]='Terminated' THEN 'Delete'
                                        WHEN G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS]<>'Terminated' THEN 'Update' 
                                    END,
[SUPP_STAFF].[SUPPORT_STAFF_FUNCTION]   =   CASE    WHEN G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS]='Terminated' THEN NULL
                                                    WHEN G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS]<>'Terminated' THEN G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL]
                                            END

WHEN NOT MATCHED  AND G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY] = 'CC1' 
                    AND G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS] IN ('A, S') 
THEN
INSERT(         [GGID],
                [FIRST_NAME],               
                [LAST_NAME],                
                [EMAIL],                    
                [GENDER],                   
                [DATE_OF_BIRTH],            
                [LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_CODE],
                [LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_NAME],
                [GCM_ROLE],                 
                [BU_CODE],                  
                [BU_NAME],                  
                [SBU_CODE],                 
                [SBU_NAME],                 
                [GRADE],                    
                [EMPLOYEE_STATUS],          
                [EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY],        
                [START_DATE],               
                [UPDATE_DATE],              
                [UPDATE_USER],
                [SUPPORT_STAFF_FUNCTION]    
)
VALUES (     
                G_SOURCE.[GLOBAL_ID],
                G_SOURCE.[FIRST_NAME],  
                G_SOURCE.[LAST_NAME],
                G_SOURCE.[EMAIL],
                G_SOURCE.[Gender],
                G_SOURCE.[DATE_OF_BIRTH],
                G_SOURCE.[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY_CODE],
                G_SOURCE.[LEGAL_ENTITY_COUNTRY],
                G_SOURCE.[JOB_NAME],
                G_SOURCE.[BU_CODE],
                G_SOURCE.[BU_NAME],
                G_SOURCE.[SBU_CODE],
                G_SOURCE.[SBU_NAME],
                G_SOURCE.[GRADE_LETTER],
                G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS],
                G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL],
                G_SOURCE.[FIRST_JOINING_DATE],
                GETDATE(),
                'Insert',
                G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL]

        )

OUTPUT $action,
```

INSERTED.GGID AS GGID; 
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Is the condition `G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY] = 'CC1' 
                    AND G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS] IN ('A, S') ` maybe false?

Comment: As an unrelated note I advise you to adopt a cleaner style to format your code. This current style makes it hard to work with the query.

Comment: I mean I only want to insert the records of the source table where the category ='cc1' and employee_status in (a,s) in source..Currently, the data in the target table gets updated with that of the source but the data in source which has the category ='cc1' and employee_status in (a,s)  and does not exist in Target is not inserted in the Target table..Although, I am not getting any error but the purpose is not filled!! :(

Comment: You don't have `category` in your match conditions.

Comment: but i need to check category only when for the case of inserts!! for 'WHEN NOT MATCHED'  then i need to chek the category and perform insert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the error. The error was at the below 2 places -

```
CASE WHEN G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY] = 'DSS' THEN G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL] ELSE '' END AS [CATEGORY],
```

I replaced it with

```
CASE WHEN G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY] = 'DSS' THEN G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY_DETAIL] ELSE '' 
END AS [EMPLOYEE_FUNCTION],
```

Also I included one more column in my Source query which was missing-

```
G_UNIQUE.[CATEGORY],
```

Also, there below wrong code

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED  AND G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY] = 'CC1' 
                AND G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS] IN ('A, S')
```

was replaced by the below correct code-

```
    WHEN NOT MATCHED  AND G_SOURCE.[CATEGORY] = 'CC1' 
                    AND G_SOURCE.[EMPLOYEE_STATUS] IN ('Active', 'Suspended')
```

Actually, I was missing 1 source column and was checking the value for the same while inserting and hence the insert was failing.
Also,in the source for Employee_status i checked the values as A,S and T and then replaced them with Active,Suspended,Terminated but while inserting in the When not matched , i was checking the value for A,S,T which every time was returning false and hence insert failed.

Answer (score 1):

One of your assumptions is wrong. Either the source query has less rows than you think, or there is a match, or the insert condition is not met. Otherwise the query is OK.

To debug this I'd insert the source query into a temp table and manually inspect its contents to make sure they are what you expect.

You can then join to the target to see if your inserts maybe are converted to updates (e.g. `select * from Source join Target on ...`). Internally, a `MERGE` is just a full outer join anyway and you can reproduce that manually.

Right now nobody can tell you the exact answer. You need to debug this yourself and examine your data.